# What to do to get only one List?

Tags: c#, list

Hello i have a method that compares the objects of 2 Lists for differences. Right now this works but only for one property at a time.

Here is the Method:

```
    public SPpowerPlantList compareTwoLists(string sqlServer, string database, DateTime timestampCurrent, string noteCurrent, DateTime timestampOld, string noteOld)
    {

        int count = 0;
        SPpowerPlantList powerPlantListCurrent = loadProjectsAndComponentsFromSqlServer(sqlServer, database, timestampCurrent, noteCurrent);
        SPpowerPlantList powerPlantListOld = loadProjectsAndComponentsFromSqlServer(sqlServer, database, timestampOld, noteOld);
        SPpowerPlantList powerPlantListDifferences = new SPpowerPlantList();
        count = powerPlantListOld.Count - powerPlantListCurrent.Count;

        var differentObjects = powerPlantListCurrent.Where(p => !powerPlantListOld.Any(l => p.mwWeb == l.mwWeb)).ToList();

        foreach (var differentObject in differentObjects)
        {
            powerPlantListDifferences.Add(differentObject);
        }

        return powerPlantListDifferences;

    }
```

This works and i get 4 Objects in the new List. The Problem is that i have a few other properties that i need to compare. Instead of mwWeb for example name. When i try to change it i need for every new property a new List and a new Foreach-Loop.

e.g.

```
    int count = 0;
    SPpowerPlantList powerPlantListCurrent = loadProjectsAndComponentsFromSqlServer(sqlServer, database, timestampCurrent, noteCurrent);
    SPpowerPlantList powerPlantListOld = loadProjectsAndComponentsFromSqlServer(sqlServer, database, timestampOld, noteOld);
    SPpowerPlantList powerPlantListDifferences = new SPpowerPlantList();
    SPpowerPlantList powerPlantListDifferences2 = new SPpowerPlantList();

    count = powerPlantListOld.Count - powerPlantListCurrent.Count;

    var differentObjects = powerPlantListCurrent.Where(p => !powerPlantListOld.Any(l => p.mwWeb == l.mwWeb)).ToList();
    var differentObjects2 = powerPlantListCurrent.Where(p => !powerPlantListOld.Any(l => p.shortName == l.shortName)).ToList();

    foreach (var differentObject in differentObjects)
    {
        powerPlantListDifferences.Add(differentObject);
    }

    foreach (var differentObject in differentObjects2)
    {
        powerPlantListDifferences2.Add(differentObject);
    }

    return powerPlantListDifferences;
```

Is there a way to prevent this? or to make more querys and get only 1 List with all different Objects back?

I tried it with `except` and `intersect` but that didnt worked.
So any help or advise would be great and thx for your time.

PS: If there is something wrong with my question-style please say it to me becouse i try to learn to ask better questions.

Comment: I think you need to implement IEqualityComparer for your objects. Then `except` and `intersect` will work. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2011/04/05/linq-distinct-and-iequalitycomparer-implementation/

Comment: Why not just override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to simply chain the properties that you wanted to compare within your [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) clause using OR statements :

```
// This should get you any elements that have different A properties, B properties, etc.
var different = current.Where(p => !old.Any(l => p.A == l.A || p.B == l.B))
                       .ToList();
```

If that doesn't work and you really want to use the [`Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.100).aspx) methods to properly compare the objects, you could write your own custom [`IEqualityComparer<YourPowerPlant>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.100).aspx) to use to properly compare them :

```
class PowerPlantComparer : IEqualityComparer<YourPowerPlant>
{
    // Powerplants are are equal if specific properties are equal. 
    public bool Equals(YourPowerPlant x, YourPowerPlant y)
    {
        // Check whether the compared objects reference the same data. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        // Checks the other properties to compare (examples using mwWeb and shortName)
        return x.mwWeb == y.mwWeb && x.shortName == y.shortName;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 

    public int GetHashCode(YourPowerPlant powerPlant)
    {
        // Check whether the object is null 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(powerPlant, null)) return 0;

        // Get hash code for the mwWeb field if it is not null. 
        int hashA = powerPlant.mwWeb == null ? 0 : powerPlant.mwWeb.GetHashCode();

        // Get hash code for the shortName field if it is not null. 
        int hashB = powerPlant.shortName == null ? 0 : powerPlant.shortName.GetHashCode();

        // Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashA ^ hashB;
    }
}
```

and then you could likely use something like one of the following depending on your needs :

```
var different = current.Except(old,new PowerPlantComparer());
```

or :

```
var different = current.Intersect(old,new PowerPlantComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `IEqualityComparer` as Rion Williams suggested, if you'd like a more flexible solution you can split logic in to two parts. First create helper method that accepts two lists, and function where you can define what properties you wish to compare. For example :

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static SPpowerPlantList GetDifference(this SPpowerPlantList current, SPpowerPlantList old, Func<PowerPlant, PowerPlant, bool> func)
    {
        var diff = current.Where(p => old.All(l => func(p, l))).ToList();
        var result = new SPpowerPlantList();

        foreach (var item in diff) result.Add(item);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
public SPpowerPlantList compareTwoLists(string sqlServer, string database,
                                        DateTime timestampCurrent, string noteCurrent, 
                                                   DateTime timestampOld, string noteOld)
{      
     var powerPlantListCurrent = ...;
     var powerPlantListOld = ...;

     var diff = powerPlantListCurrent.GetDifference(
          powerPlantListOld,
             (x, y) => x.mwWeb != y.mwWeb ||
                       x.shortName != y.shortName);


   return diff;
}
```

P.S. if it better suits your needs, you could move method inside of existing class :

```
public class MyClass
{
   public SPpowerPlantList GetDifference(SPpowerPlantList current, SPpowerPlantList old, Func<PowerPlant, PowerPlant, bool> func)
   {
      ...
   }        
}
```

And call it (inside of class) :

```
var result = GetDifference(currentValues, oldValues, (x, y) => x.mwWeb != y.mwWeb);
```

Comment: just tried it and this one works great too but i am not supposed to add a new class.....

Comment: @ltanderl there is no real reason to add class Helper - it's just for convenience, you could remove `this` keyword  and move method in existing class as a normal static method.

Comment: oh didnt noticed that i give it another try. Thanks

Comment: @ltanderl Edited my question to explain it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to compare some unique identifier (ID)

```
var differentObjects = powerPlantListCurrent
    .Where(p => !powerPlantListOld.Any(l => p.Id == l.Id)
    .ToList();
```

If the other properties might have been updated and you want to check that too, you'll have to compare all of them to detect changes made to existing elements:

Implement a camparison-method (`IComparable`, `IEquatable`, `IEqualityComparer`, or override `Equals`) or, if that's not possible because you didn't write the class yourself (code generated or external assembly), write a method to compare two of those `SPpowerPlantList` elements and use that instead of comparing every single property in Linq. For example:

```
public bool AreThoseTheSame(SPpowerPlantList a,SPpowerPlantList b)
{
    if(a.mwWeb != b.mwWeb) return false;
    if(a.shortName != b.shortName) return false;
    //etc.
    return true;
}
```

Then replace your difference call with this:

```
var differentObjects = powerPlantListCurrent
    .Where(p => !powerPlantListOld.Any(l => AreThoseTheSame(p,l))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It is easier and more beautiful to use IEqualityComparer. :-)

Comment: @Sebastian-Schulz Agreed, that's why I mentioned it as a preferred option :), edit: Oh wait - that's the one interface I forgot

Comment: Remember when you override `Equals` you must override `GetHashCode` as well!